# PrimeNg TabView does not work with observables

Tags: angular, observable, primeng

I'm trying to populate PrimeNG TabView tabs by fetching data from the server. However, they don't seem to play well with Observables. I've posted an example here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-nx7ryc?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

- With no initial items in my Angular component, dynamic tabpanels won't be displayed at all
- With one initial item, dynamic tabpanels will only be displayed when the INITIAL tabpanel is clicked

Can you please suggest a workaround for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To handle the no-initial-items scenario, you could just put an `*ngIf="this.items?.length"` on your `<p-tabView>` element.

To handle both the no-initial-items and the one-initial-item scenarios, you could use the `activeIndex` property of `<p-tabView>`:

```html
<p-tabView [activeIndex]="activeIndex"> <----- add [activeIndex] here
    <p-tabPanel *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" [header]="item.username" [selected]="i == 0">
        [{{item.username}}]
    </p-tabPanel>
</p-tabView>
```

Setting that value after your data has arrived will trigger `<p-tabView>` to refresh itself.

So your component would look like this:

```js
items = [
  { username: "INITIAL"}
];

activeIndex: number; // <--- declare but don't initialize

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
  const source = this.get$();
  const subscribe = source.subscribe(result => {
      this.items = result.slice(0,3);
      this.activeIndex = 0; // <---- set to 0 to trigger p-tabView refresh
  });   
}
```

[Here's a fork of your StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-y9zrap?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) demonstrating this approach.

Comment: Thanks, it works now! Just curious - how did you find this activeIndex trick - was it in their documentation?

Comment: @marin, yes, `activeIndex` is in their [TabView documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/tabview) in a section called **Programmatic Control**.

Answer (score 0):

I reported a very similar issue to the PrimeNG team and PrimeNG has fixed it with version 10.0.1.   Try installing primeng@10.0.1.

https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/9331

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar case with the TabPanel.
In PrimeNG 11 it does not respond to changes to the "isValidPaymentTerms" property.
It only does it once you select the page.

```
<p-tabPanel header="Exceptional Payment Terms"
                    [selected]="Constants.C_PAYMENT == vTabSelected"
                    *[rightIcon]="isValidPaymentTerms ? '': 'fas fa-exclamation-triangle'"*>
...
        </p-tabPanel>
```